# permute dataframe but must have unique rows

Tags: r, algorithm

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
d <- data.frame(time = c(1,3,5,6,11,15,15,18,18,20), side = c("L", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R","R","R"), id = c(1,2,1,2,4,3,4,2,1,1), stringsAsFactors = F)
d

   time side id
1     1    L  1
2     3    R  2
3     5    R  1
4     6    L  2
5    11    L  4
6    15    L  3
7    15    L  4
8    18    R  2
9    18    R  1
10   20    R  1
```

I wish to permute the id variable and keep the other two constant.  However, importantly, in my final permutations I do not want to have the same id on the same side at the same time.  For instance, there are two times/sides where this might occur. In the original data at time 15 and 18 there are two unique ids at the same side (left for time 15 and right for time 18).  If I permute using `sample` there is a chance that the same id shows up at the same time/side combination.

For example,

```
set.seed(11)
data.frame(time=d$time, side=d$side, id=sample(d$id))

   time side id
1     1    L  1
2     3    R  1
3     5    R  4
4     6    L  1
5    11    L  4
6    15    L  2
7    15    L  3
8    18    R  2
9    18    R  2
10   20    R  1
```

Here, id=2 appears on two rows at time 18 on side "R".  This is not allowed in the permutation I need.

One solution would be to brute force this - e.g. say I needed 100 permutation, I could generate 500 and discard those that fail the criteria. However, in my real data I have hundreds of rows and just using `sample`almost always leads to a failure.  I wonder if there is a better algorithm for doing this? Perhaps a birth-death algorithm?

Comment: You are looking for random permutation without duplication, right? You are not looking for any sort of cross-product permutation, I'm assuming.

Comment: @r2evans yes exactly - a permutation without duplication.

Comment: Does your sampling need to preserve the probability for each `time`? For instance, for rows other than 6-7, one would expect (asymptotically) that time=15 would appear twice as often as time=1.

Comment: @r2evans yes- the times in the permuted data should be in the same frequency/proportion as the original data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- data.frame(time = c(1,3,5,6,11,15,15,18,18,20), side = c("L", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R","R","R"), id = c(1,2,1,2,4,3,4,2,1,1), stringsAsFactors = F)
d <- rownames_to_column(d)
```

I want the rownames to put it back in order at the end.

You need a function that takes a vector (like your `id` vector) and returns a sample of size `n` with the constraint that the values have to be different, as in the following (which assumes the sampling you want can actually take place, i.e. you haven't run out of items to sample). For convenience this also returns the "leftovers" that weren't sampled:

```
samp_uniq_n <- function(vec, n) {
  x <- vec
  out <- rep(NA, n)
  for(i in 1:n) {
    # Here would be a good place to make sure sampling is even possible.
    probs <- prop.table(table(x))
    out[i] <- sample(unique(x), 1, prob=probs)
    x <- x[x != out[i]]
    vec <- vec[-min(which(vec == out[i]))]
  }
  return(list(out=out, vec=vec))
}
```

Now, we need to split the data into a list of rows that have the same `time` and `side` and start the sampling with the largest such:

```
id <- d$id
d_split <- d %>% select(-id) %>% split(., list(d$time, d$side), drop = TRUE)
d_split_desc <- d_split[order(-sapply(d_split, nrow))]
```

Then we can do the sampling itself:

```
for(i in seq_along(d_split_desc)) {
  samp <- samp_uniq_n(id, nrow(d_split_desc[[i]]))
  this_id <- samp$out
  d_split_desc[[i]]$id <- this_id
  id <- samp$vec
}
```

Finally, some cleanup:

```
d_permute <- do.call(rbind, d_split_desc) %>% 
  arrange(as.numeric(rowname)) %>% 
  select(-rowname)
```

Putting all this in a big function is an annoyance I'll leave to anyone who is interested.